# why NONE-"Orphaned Process Groups" required child and parent in different process group of same session?

Tags: linux, process

In the Advanced Programming in the UNIX ,section 9.10

```
"The POSIX.1 definition of an orphaned process group is one in which the
parent of every member is either itself a member of the group or is not 
a member of the group's session. Another way of wording this is that the 
process group is not orphaned as long as a process in the group has a 
parent in a different process group but in the same session. "
```

it also said that:

**"If the process group is not orphaned, there is a chance that one of those 
parents in a different process group but in the same session will restart
a stopped process in the process group that is not orphaned."**

so, if the process group is orphaned:

1)the child process and its parent process are in the same process group

2)the child process and its parent process are in the different process group of different session

I am wondering if there is no chance for the parent process to restart its child process when the child process stopped under the above two circumstances.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I have revised the question.